# Reading from barcode scanner to a text file in raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a problem that I want to read the input that read by "bar code" and save it to a text file.

Raspberry pi B+ with latest version of wheezy.

"bar code" scanner "data logic q w 2100".

Comment: This question shows no attempt at the problem first... Please read the How To Ask guide before posting again.

Comment: @LukePark Park i know that barcode scanner is used as keyboard wing when it connected as a usp but when i plugged it into my rasbperry and open a leafpad document it doesn`t work and there is no data appeared

Comment: The LED comes on? When you connect the device, nothing happens?

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem with few steps simply:

1) make sure your repo is updated.

2) your barcode scanner is selected as USB KEYBOARD as shown in img:"1.PNG"
[DATALOGIC QW2100 KEYBOARD SELECTION][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxkG2.png

3) in Ubuntu barcode scanner capture data and view it in any window can capture input " terminal or text file " or any other thing.

4) in raspberry pi problem is that barcode scanner captured or read value is made into "/dev/hidraw0" for example.."that file is created auto when your barcode is connected to your raspi.

HERE IS SOME SIMPLE PYTHON CODE TO CAPTURE DATA FROM THAT FILE ONLY WHEN BARCODE IS CONNECTED TO RASPI:

```
import sys

done = False

while not done:

   hid = { 4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f', 10: 'g', 11: 'h', 12: 'i', 13: 'j', 14: 'k', 15: 'l', 16: 'm', 17: 'n', 18: 'o', 19: 'p', 20: 'q', 21: 'r', 22: 's', 23: 't', 24: 'u', 25: 'v', 26: 'w', 27: 'x', 28: 'y', 29: 'z', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '3', 33: '4', 34: '5', 35: '6', 36: '7', 37: '8', 38: '9', 39: '0', 44: ' ', 45: '-', 46: '=', 47: '[', 48: ']', 49: '\\', 51: ';' , 52: '\'', 53: '~', 54: ',', 55: '.', 56: '/'  }

   hid2 = { 4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'E', 9: 'F', 10: 'G', 11: 'H', 12: 'I', 13: 'J', 14: 'K', 15: 'L', 16: 'M', 17: 'N', 18: 'O', 19: 'P', 20: 'Q', 21: 'R', 22: 'S', 23: 'T', 24: 'U', 25: 'V', 26: 'W', 27: 'X', 28: 'Y', 29: 'Z', 30: '!', 31: '@', 32: '#', 33: '$', 34: '%', 35: '^', 36: '&', 37: '*', 38: '(', 39: ')', 44: ' ', 45: '_', 46: '+', 47: '{', 48: '}', 49: '|', 51: ':' , 52: '"', 53: '~', 54: '<', 55: '>', 56: '?'  }

   fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')


   ss = ""

   shift = False

   done = False

   while not done:

  ## Get the character from the HID
  buffer = fp.read(8)
  for c in buffer:
     if ord(c) > 0:

        ##  40 is carriage return which signifies
        ##  we are done looking for characters
        if int(ord(c)) == 40:
           done = True
           break;

        ##  If we are shifted then we have to 
        ##  use the hid2 characters.
        if shift: 

           ## If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
           if int(ord(c)) == 2 :
              shift = True

           ## if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
           else:
              ss += hid2[ int(ord(c)) ]
              shift = False

        ##  If we are not shifted then use
        ##  the hid characters

        else:

           ## If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
           if int(ord(c)) == 2 :
              shift = True

           ## if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
           else:
              ss += hid[ int(ord(c)) ]     
 print ss

 ##DONE
```

I ADDED FIRST WHILE LOOP TO MAKE SCRIPT WORK CONTINUOUS TILL U KILL IT WITH "CTRL+C".

ANOTHER THING: IMAGE IS FOR DATALOGIC BARCODE CODE SCANNER QW2100 LITE, SO CHECK YOUR BARCODE MANUEL CAREFULLY TOO.

Answer (score 0):

If the LED comes on, I suggest you to boot your raspberry with barcode scanner plug in, open terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

After that, reboot and open a txt file a try to scan a barcode; Pay attention that barcode is recognized by scanner.

I bought a barcode scanner and I have the same problem me too. In this way I solved.