# odoo - unable to fetch data from barcode scanner connected to POS box

Tags: odoo, barcode-scanner, odoo-10

I am using Odoo version 10.0 and I have got Point of Sale module installed. I have connected receipt printer and barcode scanner with the POS Box  and they are shown connected in the status page `(192.168.x.x/hw_proxy/status)`. In the Point of Sale settings, I have indicated the IP address of the POS box and checked 'Barcode scanner' and 'Receipt Printer' options.

Receipt printer is working fine, however, the problem is that whenever I scan the barcode, I am not getting any response. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Install "Barcode Scanner Hardware Driver" module and check.

Comment: I did but no luck

Comment: Check drivers in your system (i.e. Linux/Windows) whether barcode scanner drivers are there and working properly or not. After that in your POSBox image check, you have hardware modules and configuration of that hardware modules are proper or not.

Comment: The driver is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865384/reading-from-barcode-scanner-to-a-text-file-in-raspberry-pi) link answer given by @Ahmed Shoman. I changed the configuration of my barcode scanner to USB Keyboard. So accomplished this by scanning barcode in LS-2208 manual page number 109 (HID Keyboard Emulation).

[image]